# Parsing OpenXML with elements that are also siblings with the same name

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery, openxml

I have an XML data structure that currently looks like this and is saved in table XML_STLD (which I can't change, its an output from a proprietary system):

```
<rootnode>
    <group id="00001" status="online">
        <order OrdId="42" Type="Sale">
            <Item code="1234" qty="1" unitprice="38.00" rank="0" level="0">
                <Item code="5678" qty="1" unitprice="11.00" rank="0" level="1">
                    <Item code="9876" qty="1" unitprice="8.00" rank="0" level="2">
                    <Tax percent="12"/></Item>
                <Tax percent="12"/></Item>
            <Tax percent="12"/></Item>
            <Item code="7654" qty="1" unitprice="98.00" rank="1" level="0">
                <Item code="3211" qty="1" unitprice="8.00" rank="1" level="1">
                <Tax percent="12"/></Item>
            <Tax percent="12"/></Item>
        </order>
    </group>
</rootnode>
```

My OpenXML query looks like this:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XML_STLD

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT GroupId, GroupStatus, OrdId, OrdType, ICode, IQty, IPrice, 
IRank, ILevel, ITax

FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'rootnode/group/order/Item/Tax')
WITH 
(
GroupId int '../../../@id',
GroupStatus [varchar](100) '../../../@status',
OrdId int '../../@OrdId',
OrdType [varchar](100) '../../@Type',
ICode int '../@code',
IQty int '../@qty',
IPrice numeric(18,2) '../@unitprice',
IRank int '../@rank',
ILevel int '../@level',
ITax int '@percent'
) 

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Now my query works really well but it has a big problem, it only returns the first item and its related tax sibling. To give a short description of the  element:

Each item has a rank and a level. The first three as you can see are siblings of each other and has a rank of "0". However, the grandparent has a level of "0", a parent of "1" and so on. These items are nested as each sibling is part of a bigger package (its parent). The second stand alone item on the order has a rank of "1" and the levels start again at "0".

My current output is:

```
GroupId | GroupStatus | OrdId | OrdType | ICode | IQty | IPrice | IRank | ILevel | ITax
------- | ----------- | ----- | ------- | ----- | ---- | ------ | ----- | ------ | ----
1       | online      | 42    | Sale    | 1234  | 1    | 38.00  | 0     | 0      | 12
1       | online      | 42    | Sale    | 7654  | 1    | 98.00  | 1     | 0      | 12
```

My required output is:

```
GroupId | GroupStatus | OrdId | OrdType | ICode | IQty | IPrice | IRank | ILevel | ITax
------- | ----------- | ----- | ------- | ----- | ---- | ------ | ----- | ------ | ----
1       | online      | 42    | Sale    | 1234  | 1    | 38.00  | 0     | 0      | 12
1       | online      | 42    | Sale    | 5678  | 1    | 11.00  | 0     | 1      | 12
1       | online      | 42    | Sale    | 9876  | 1    | 8.00   | 0     | 2      | 12
1       | online      | 42    | Sale    | 7654  | 1    | 98.00  | 1     | 0      | 12
1       | online      | 42    | Sale    | 3211  | 1    | 8.00   | 1     | 1      | 12
```

I'm also happy if someone can assist with a XQuery workaround. Currently using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using XQuery you can shred the XML on `group` element, and `Item` element wherever it is located within `group`. Then you can select required values starting from those 2 elements :

```
select 
    grp.value('@id', 'int') AS GroupId,
    grp.value('@status', 'varchar(100)') AS GroupStatus,
    grp.value('(order/@OrdId)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS OrdId,
    grp.value('(order/@Type)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS OrdType,
    item.value('@code', 'int') AS ICode,
    item.value('@qty', 'int') AS IQty
from @xml.nodes('rootnode/group') A(grp)
outer apply grp.nodes('.//Item') AS B(item)
```

Assume `@xml` is XML variable declared as follow :

```
declare @xml AS XML = '<rootnode>
    <group id="00001" status="online">
        <order OrdId="42" Type="Sale">
            <Item code="1234" qty="1" unitprice="38.00" rank="0" level="0">
                <Item code="5678" qty="1" unitprice="11.00" rank="0" level="1">
                    <Item code="9876" qty="1" unitprice="8.00" rank="0" level="2">
                        <Tax percent="12" />
                    </Item>
                    <Tax percent="12" />
                </Item>
                <Tax percent="12" />
            </Item>
            <Item code="7654" qty="1" unitprice="98.00" rank="1" level="0">
                <Item code="3211" qty="1" unitprice="8.00" rank="1" level="1">
                    <Tax percent="12" />
                </Item>
                <Tax percent="12" />
            </Item>
        </order>
    </group>
</rootnode>'
```

**output :**

[image]

Selection of columns `IPrice`, `IRank`, `ILevel` and `ITax` are left as an exercise :)

Comment: Thank you very much! This was very helpful. Just a quick question, it seems to be running much slower than OpenXML. Is there a reason for this? Or is it just on my side? The XML file I'm dealing with is about 1.5GB per day.